# Can you apply one property in a class for a DIV differently for two elements?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a DIV whose background color is light grey, but I want the background color for HRs to be black. I'd like to have one class for the DIV that can control both of these so I don't have to apply a separate class for each HR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is not possible. However, you might be looking for this:

```
div hr {
  background-color: black;
}
```

`div hr` will match all `hr` which are descendants of `div`. This means you *do not have to apply a class for each `hr` element*, which is what you requested in the question.

For direct descendants only (children), use `div > hr`.

Answer (score 0):

A class can't control both of them, but it's possible to not have to apply a separate class for each HR.